# Asp.net core redirection

Tags: asp.net, redirect, telegram

I`m developing asp.net core application to be used in telegram bot. I`m using razor pages and have 3 of them: Start, Questions, QuestionAnswered

On Start there is telegram`s javascript, which provides my application with userId and username.
When app got userId and username it redirects to page Questions using JavaScript :

```
`document.location.replace(`/Start?handler=UserId&UserId=${ID}&UserName=${Name}`);`
```

Then there is interaction with user ( user answers some question)
And when user answers last question application must redirect him to page QuestionsAnswered.
And here is where problem appears. **Internal telegram browser asks for confirmation and then opens link in another browser.**

[Browser confirm request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJi6v.jpg)

I have tried using Redirect(), RedirectPermament(), RedirectToPage(), and everithing works the same.

I realy don`t need thic confirmation in browser.
What should I use instead:

```
`return RedirectToPage("QuestionAnswered", new { Id = Id });`
```

In order it worked the same as `document.location.replace` ?

Comment: When you use `document.location.replace`, the redirect is happened on client-side while the `RedirectToPage` is server-side redirect method. It will send a response to client. Try to use client-side redirect js method in razor page: `window.location.replace("/QuestionAnswered?id=" + Id);
`